# How to use client component to render interactive UI?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using Nextjs with the App Router. I am trying to add a `<Header />` component to the default layout file. Since it has interactive UI to show a mobile menu, I used `use client` at the top of the file. However, this does not seem to be doing anything.

I used "npx create-next-app@latest". All I did was add a `components` folder within the `src` folder. I added a file `Header.js` and added the following code:

```
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the root `layout.js` within the `/app` folder, I added the following code:

```
import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Header from "../components/Header";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Header />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

The counter is not going up when clicking the button. I've tried replicating with codesandbox, but magically on the [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zealous-cloud-7n4zly?file=/app/layout.tsx:15,28) is **does** seem to be working propertly. I am completely clueless as to what is different between the 2 examples and why it does not work locally...

Comment: This way, it doesn't look feasible to solve the issue or know where it lies when it's running in codesandbox.
I'd suggest to try replacing codesandbox files one-by-one with your files. You should get where the issue is.

Comment: @SaahilM I did. Still doesn't work. Just to be clear; when you create a new next project and follow the exact steps I did, your counter does go up when clicking the button? Could you try maybe? Literally all I did was just add a `<header>` component with `use client`....

Comment: Tried with the steps you wrote, works for me. Added the Header.js in components folder and imported and rendered the same in layout.js. Number of clicks getting logged.

Comment: @Reinier68 How are you running the app?

Comment: @RobinThomas Just locally, `npm run dev`.